# iOS unwind segue breaking protocol/delegate. Why?

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, mqtt

I have an iPhone app that presents information about a video playing on a kiosk-like device. The kiosk is running a python script that sends out video information via MQTT.

The iPhone uses `CocoaMQTT` to listen for video information. When the information (title etc.) is received the app presents it modally in `NowPlayingVC` with a segue from `MenuVC`. When the video is finished, the kiosk sends a 'finished' message and `NowPlayingVC` triggers an unwind segue to `MenuVC`. This process works fine the first time through, but fails after the first time.

To handle the MQTT communication I am using a shared instance of a model called `MQTTManager` that defines various protocol functions that are called in response to MQTT messages published by the kiosk. One of these functions is `vhPlayingVideoInfoLoaded` and provides the information about the playing video sent from the kiosk (e.g. `MQTT Manager` calls `self.delegate?.vhPlayingVideoInfoLoaded!(description: String(descriptParts[1]), videoFile: String(descriptParts[0]))`)

After the first time through and the unwind segue `MQTTManager` does what it's supposed to, but `MenuVC`, the delegate of `MQTTManager`, stops responding as the delegate -- it's as if the unwind segue has broken the delegation.

As an experiment, I replaced the unwind segue with a storyboard segue from `NowPlayingVC` to `MenuVC` and everything work exactly as it should the first time and after. The problem with that approach is that one ends up with a big memory-consuming stack of VCs that are confusing to the user.

Can anyone explain why the unwind segue is breaking the protocol/delegate? Is there a way to fix it? I'm happy to provide code, but I am guessing, being self-taught, that I am missing an obvious issue with my approach.

I have tired to refresh the delegate by putting `mqtt.delegate=self` in various view functions, but that had no effect.

Any thoughts would be gratefully received, thanks. I'm using Xcode 13.3 and targeting iOS 13.

Comment: I'm guessing `MenuVC` sets *itself* as the MQTT delegate... a delegate func is called and `MenuVC` presents `NowPlayingVC` -- and ``NowPlayingVC` sets ***itself*** as the delegate? Then when ***it*** receives the "finished" message, it goes away and we're back at `MenuVC`? So, you need to set `MenuVC` as the delegate again.

Comment: DonMag, you got the idea exactly. The thing is I don't how/where to do is to reset `MenuVC` as the MQTT delegate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming:

- your "present `NowPlayingVC` modally" segue has an identifier of "didStart"
- your unwind segue has an identifier of "unwind"

You would have code along these lines:

```
class MenuVC: UIViewController, MQTTDelegate {
    
    let mqtt = MQTTObject.sharedInstance
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // set mqtt delegate to self
        mqtt.delegate = self
    }
    
    // mqtt sends a "player started playing" to its delegate (which is self)
    func didStart() {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "didStart", sender: self)
    }
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let vc = segue.destination as? NowPlayingVC {
            // set mqtt delegate to the segue destination controller
            mqtt.delegate = vc
        }
    }
    
    @IBAction func unwind( _ seg: UIStoryboardSegue) {
        // set mqtt delegate to self again
        mqtt.delegate = self
    }
}

class NowPlayingVC: UIViewController, MQTTDelegate {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    // mqtt sends a "player finished playing" to its delegate (which is self)
    func didFinish() {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwind", sender: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep. I just figured this out after reading https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/resource_management/dismissing_a_view_controller_with_an_unwind_segue and was about to answer my own question. Thanks for your time and effort. Much appreciated.